# Cannot open file downloaded from an Rails application in Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

If I try to download a file in my rails application, I am only able to save the file, the open button is not there.

I have tried to deactivate all security Features which could lead to such a behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out rails sets the `X-Download-Options`-Header to `noopen` per default:

> The X-Download-Options HTTP header has only one option:
>   X-Download-Options: noopen. This is for Internet Explorer from version
>   8 on to instruct the browser not to open a download directly in the
>   browser, but instead to provide only the ‘Save’ option. The user has
>   to first save it and then open it in an application. The reason for
>   this is that when HTML files download from the application, the
>   browser will render it directly inline. That means that the file
>   renders as part of the application and has direct access to the
>   security context of it, meaning it may run phishing attacks or maybe
>   access critical domain cookies.